# Ruby CSV get 5 top expenses with name from bank statement

Tags: ruby

I have CSV bank statement :

```
Transaction Date|Transaction Type|Transaction Description|Debit Amount
29/09/2015  DEB     TFL.GOV.UK/CP   1.5
29/09/2015  DEB     PRIMARK 674     14
29/09/2015  DEB     PRIMARK 674     7
28/09/2016  DEB     TFL             1.5
27/09/2016  DEB     TFL             1.5
26/09/2016  DEB     MCDONALDS       4.26
26/09/2016  DEB     TFL              3
26/09/2016  DEB     TFL             6.3
26/09/2017  CPT     LNK SOUTHWARK 1  10
25/09/2017  DEB     LIDL            19.3
```

I need to get 5 top expenses together with transaction name.
Example  McDonalds 4.26 and etc....

So far I managed to get only 5 top items.

require 'CSV'

```
list = []
CSV.foreach('statment_september.csv') do |row|
list << row[5].to_i
end
top_five = list.sort
top_five.last(5)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
require 'csv'

top_five = CSV.read('statment_september.csv', headers: false)
              .max_by(5) { |row| -row[3].to_f }
```